# How to calculate the Arithmetic Zeta function?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, computational-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

I consider the equation $x^2+y^2+z^3=xyz+2$ over the integers. As a variety this only has a singularity in characteristic $2$. Now I am interested in calculating the arithmetic zeta function of this variety. It is doable to calculate the Hasse-Weil zeta function, which already gives all factors except for characteristic $2$ reduction.

The first problem is that I am not sure how the factor is even defined, as almost all sources just talk about the good reduction case.

What I hoped to do was to use the definition as
$$
\zeta_X(s) = \prod_{x}1/(1-N(x)^{-s}).
$$
If I understand correctly, to obtain the $p=2$ factor we take a product over all powers of $2$ and get a factor $1/(1-q^{-s})^{q^2+1}$ for $q=2^n$ (here I use that there are $q^2+1$ solutions in the field of $q$ elements). But it does not completely feel right to me.

Another option is using the characteristic polynomial of Frobenius at p on the inertia-invariant subspace of the $\ell$-adic cohomology of the variety. But for this option I have no idea how to even start computing any of this.

At last an option would be to magically find an non-singular model over $\mathbb{Z}$, but with some basic operations I cannot find such a model. Maybe it would also be a bit easier to look at the projective closure over the equation, for the Hasse-Weil part that would not be a problem. So if that would make this bad-reduction factor easier it might also be a good idea.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115795/euler-product-of-modular-l-series) seems relevant, especially KCd's comments. I don't know how to do this, but I think the way it's supposed to go is: (1) there are finitely many possibilities for the bad Euler factors; and (2) there is a unique choice of the bad Euler factors such that the functional equation holds.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn Thanks for the answer! It indeed seems like the functional equation should be enough to find the bad factors. Do you have any idea what this functional equation should exactly be? I found a paper by MARC HINDRY which gives some functional equation (conjecture 2.15), but there the functional equation only works for the separate $L$-functions. But as the functional equations are all shifted depending on which of the $2n$ factors it is I can't find a way to combine them. Moreover I am not sure how I can use the point counting to find the separate $L$-factors instead of $\zeta$.